# Extract line of interest from a wmic.exe call

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, wmic

On powershell i'm executing the following command:

```
$objWMI = wmic product where "name like 'app' " get PackageCache

echo $objWMI
```

Output:

```
PackageCache
C:\Windows\Installer\file.msi
```

I need to convert this output only to show this dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable in your example is converted to an array once the command is successfully run, with the path always being displayed on the 3rd line, so you can simply call $objWMI[2] to give you the directory only (we use the number 2 because if we wanted the first line we would use [0]).

All together it could be something simple like below.

```
$objWMI = wmic product where "name like 'app' " get PackageCache
$directory=$objWMI[2]
echo $directory
```

Answer (score 5):

**[Colin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63962442/45375) provides an effective solution**, though there are two **good reasons to use a *different* approach**:

- The `wmic.exe` CLI is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831568(v=ws.11)#wmi-providers) (as are PowerShell's `*-Wmi*` cmdlets such as `Get-WmiObject`)
- As an *external program*, it can only communicate *text* to PowerShell, which then requires *parsing* that text to get the information of interest, which is both cumbersome and brittle.

---

Using the **[`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) cmdlet** avoids both problems: The CIM cmdlets are the recommended way to interact with WMI and, as a native PowerShell cmdlet, **`Get-CimInstance` returns *objects* rather than text, whose *properties* you can access** in a robust manner:

```
# Get the Win32_Product instance of interest and output its
# .PackageCache propertly value.
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "app"').PackageCache
```

The above directly outputs a string such as `C:\Windows\Installer\file.msi`; simply prepend something like `$packagePath =`  to capture it in a variable.

**Caveat**:

**The `Win32_Product` CIM/WMI class should be avoided, if possible**, because [**its use is excessively slow and can have side effects**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974524/event-log-message-indicates-that-the-windows-installer-reconfigured-al) (emphasis added):

> Win32_product Class is **not query-optimized**. Queries such as “select * from Win32_Product where (name like 'Sniffer%')” require WMI to use the MSI provider to enumerate all of the installed products and then parse the full list sequentially to handle the “where” clause. This process also **initiates a consistency check of packages installed, verifying and repairing the install. With an account with only user privileges, as the user account may not have access to quite a few locations, may cause delay in application launch and an event 11708 stating an installation failure**.